# Django 1.11 - Static files not served - PythonAnywhere

Tags: django, web-deployment, django-staticfiles, pythonanywhere

I am deploying a django 1.11 app to a PythonAnywhere enviroment.

The settings file has 'django.contrib.staticfiles' added to the INSTALLED_APPS and the static config

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_col')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

Folder structure of static folder:

```
├── css
├── fonts
├── img
├── jquery.templates
└── js
    └── jquery
```

When developing the app locally I was using "/static/jquery.templates/jquery.templates.js" without problems when doing manage.py runserver, but it doesn't work in deployment where I got no static files served whatsoever.

I executed `manage.py collectstatic` which worked without errors, but it moved the folder "jquery.templates" to js one:

```
static_col/
├── admin
    ...
├── css
├── fonts
├── img
└── js
    ├── jquery
    └── jquery.templates
```

**Problem**

The other static files are served, apparently, but the problem is that the link /static/js/jquery.templates/jquery.templates.js is not found. Obviously neither the /static/jquery.templates/jquery.templates.js link does not work. I have not idea how to approach this.

Serving static files is a pain with Django and I haven't found yet a working guide for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know I ran into similar issues deploying my first project. I found the solution was to place a folder in my apps static folder named the same as the app. This prevented a lot of odd name conflicts and unexpected locations for my static files.

Structure of Application

```
django_project
├─ static_col
├─ app1
│  └─ static
│     └─ app1
│        ├─ js
│        │  ├─ jquery1.js
│        │  └─ functions1.js
│        └─ css
│           └─ styles1.css
└─ app2
   └─ static
      └─ app2
         ├─ js
         │  └─ functions2.js
         └─ css
            └─ styles2.css
```

After `manage.py collectstatic`

```
django_project
└─ static_col
   ├─ app1
   │  ├─ js
   │  │  ├─ jquery1.js
   │  │  └─ functions1.js
   │  └─ css
   │     └─ styles1.css
   └─ app2
      ├─ js
      │  └─ functions2.js
      └─ css
         └─ styles2.css
```

Then in your template make sure you use `{% static 'app1/js/functions1.js' %}` (note the addition of `app1`) to reference your files. I found this corrected most problems with `collectstatic`.

Finally, you need to make sure your server/host is actually serving the static files. You mentioned PythonAnywhere, so I would take a look at this blog post https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/60/ and double check that you have actually set up the proper directories to serve your static files (`django_project/static_col` in the above example).